# Every file of Project Unfortunately Blank while deleting .metadata folder

Tags: android, workspace

I am stuck with biggest problem now. My `.metadata` folder is deleted unforunately. after that i have tried to import again but all Project is going to blank. No one file has code.

What can i do? please help.

Comment: `.workspace` or `.metadata`?

Answer (score 0):

If you've deleted your (I assume Eclipse?) workspace folder and you have no way to recover it (have you tried the recycle bin/trash, deeper data recovery methods, etc.?), then your work may just be lost.

This seems like a good time to suggest integration of [version control](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Revision_control) into your regular workflow. [Git](http://www.git-scm.com/) in particular is a pretty popular system these days.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I will try it. but what is solution for now.